# Is this jQuery correct?

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

i would like to have smooth scroll effect on my page. And iv found this code

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This is ok, but is not working with my "go top" link. So i check other pages with tutorial and do this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  $('a.go-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

And all is working fine now. but I have no idea about jQuery, could You tell me is this correct code, or if You can, what should i change here? Thanks!

Comment: I think that this question should have been posted on [**Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ArturFilipiak To be on-topic for Code Review, the question must be posed by the author or maintainer of the code. You can't just ask for code reviews of random code that you found.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak It must be by the author. Artur, have a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Near the bottom of the page is a little checklist - if you answer all the questions with a yes, it should be on CodeReview. One of the questions asks for it to be by the author

Comment: Or maintainer. whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did not work with your go top link because you are looking only for a link with a id attributes to be clicked: `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')`. Your `go-top` is a class not an id, if you were to change it to an id you would not need the code you added.

Comment: Thank You for answer, iv changed this to id but still not working. What i have in a code:     //* Add Go To Top button in footer
add_filter( "genesis_structural_wrap-footer-widgets", 'sp_add_content_to_footer_wrap', 10, 2);
function sp_add_content_to_footer_wrap( $output, $original_output ) {
    if( 'open' == $original_output ) {
        $output = '<a href="#" id="go-top"><img src="/wp-content/themes/genesis/images/stronyfer-gotop-icon.png" alt="Przejdź do góry" /></a>' . $output;
    }
    return $output;
}

Comment: Surprisingly that was not hard to read lol. Well you have to think about what your code is doing `<a href="#" id="go-top">`. Where is this linking to? The answer is it's not being linked to anywhere you just put the pound sign inside. And again, what do you think this code does `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')`. It specifically does not match what you implemented, which is `<a href="#">`. You want to change `<a href=#>` to `<a href="wherever you want">`.

Comment: Since you want to go to the top of your page you should make a div at the top of the page like `<div id='top'>` and change `<a href="#">` to `<a href="div#top">`.

Comment: I'm using genesis theme for WordPress and there is not any id element on top, so if i can't link to any # i must stay with this additional code:  $('a.go-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
  });  ?

Comment: Keeping your additional code would be the simplest route.